# Materialize CSS - Dynamically change the background and text color of the Select Options drop-down in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, meteor, materialize

I'm using Materialize with Meteor.  I'm simply trying to change the background and text color of the option values from the select field in materialize to use my different themes. I'm able to dynamically change most of the other elements, but this one is a real pain so far. Nothing I've tried has worked.

I've tried using the included helper class colors on the `option` with no change.

I've tried `$(".dropdown-content>li>a").css("color", themeColor);` just to see if the color would change (suggested on another answer), and still no change.

I use the Blaze templating engine in meteor, and the Materialize package from Atmosphere.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add more context: which rendering engine do you use with Meteor? Do you inclde Materialize via meteor packages or via npm?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I use it via meteor packages. I've never had any luck adding it via NPM.

Comment: And which rendering do you use? Blaze, React, Angular, Vue, any else?

Answer (score 1):

## Dynamically changing the color

There are two possibilities, first that the materialize components havent beenfully initialized before you try to dynamically change their CSS (and therefore it doesn't happen). And secondly, that your selectors are not quite specific enough.

The code below acts as you wish.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-content.select-dropdown > li span").css("color", "red");
});
```

> NB Have you thought about applying a single theme class to the body of your document? It would save a lot of dynamic jquery calls after loading the page. See an example below.

---

## Demo

```js
// Initialise select
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').formSelect();
});

// Wait for page to be ready before applying CSS changes
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-content.select-dropdown > li span").css("color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select>
    <option value="" selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <label>Materialize Select</label>
</div>
```

---

## Theme Option

This would be a much better approach, using CSS selectors and then just applying a single class to the body of the page (or some other high-level parent element).

This would avoid the initialisation issue entirely.

```js
// Initialise select
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').formSelect();
});


// Change themes dynamically
$("#blue").click( function() {
  $("body").removeClass("redTheme").addClass("blueTheme");
})
$("#red").click( function() {
  $("body").removeClass("blueTheme").addClass("redTheme");
})
```

```css
.blueTheme .dropdown-content.select-dropdown > li span {
  color: blue;
}

.redTheme .dropdown-content.select-dropdown > li span {
  color: red;
}


hr {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<body>
Select theme:
<button id="red">Red Theme</button> 
<button id="blue">Blue Theme</button>
<hr>

<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select>
    <option value="" selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <label>Materialize Select</label>
</div>

</body>
```